# How to pass arguments in onClick event handler over array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have Post data and by default lets assume the posts are draft, so im displaying all drafted posts to user so they can click on publish button and publish it

```js
{!loading &&
    post.map((post) => {
      return (
        <Button onClick={() => handleClickOpenS(post._id)} color="primary" autoFocus>
          Publish
        </Button>
      );
    });
}

const handleClickOpenS = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
};
```

im Using React with material Ui , suppose there are 10 posts ,10 buttons will be rendered and when i click on the one of the button i get console log of Id of only last post ,every button is having **same id** ie,**id of last post**  and im using **functional components**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNJEI.png)

any way to slove it ,like every ***Button*** should console log their **own post id**

Comment: not sure if its typo, but here `post.map((post)` , you map over object `post` , it should be `posts.map((post)...` i guess. Missing 'S' in `posts`

Comment: nope ,its not typo.but ya makes more sense if it was posts :)

Comment: I tried your code and everything works just fine.. maybe check if your notes have different ids

Comment: oh ya ,the code works,,i tried to find wht was the problem,i was actully ,i had a button which opens a modal for confirming tht modal was creating the problem , thx for help :)